# How to deploy Java Web Application in Hostgator?

Tags: tomcat, java, web, web-applications

I have a Java Web application and I have a VPS hosting bought from Hostgator in which recently the tomcat has been installed. But I couldn't find a way to deploy my application and I talked with more than 3 Hostgator technical agents and none of them know how to deploy the Java application in tomcat in Hostgator server and they say they don't give support for hosting Java application.

Does anyone have deployed any Java application in hostgator server? If you know please help me to host my application.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of a special version of Tomcat that is only available at Hostgator. So deploying a JSP/Servlet/war on Tomcat is not specific to a hosting company.

Deploy your application as on any Tomcat. Read the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/) and you are done.

Comment: actually its not any special version. But there's no places for deploy the application in the hostgator. That's what the problem I'm having

Comment: There is no webapps folder in the file system? Then create one and configure one in Tomcat.

Comment: Nope :( but I couldn't find a way to reach the Tomcat mate, that's what my problem is :(